# Why is SKNode nodeAtPoint returning wrong node?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sknode

Apples docs state that the nodeAtPoint method on SKNode returns the deepest node in the tree.  I take this to mean that if you draw out the tree with the scene node at the top, the answer should be expected as one of the nodes at the bottom-most position in the tree.  That isn't happening for me. Here's what my tree looks like:

```
                           scene
                             |
                           world
                             |
           +------------+----+---------+------------+
           |            |              |            |
       leftArrow    rightArrow    boardLayer   statusLayer
                                       |
      +-----------+-----------+--------+-+---------------+ 
      |           |           |          |               |
    arrow     highlight     trough     rotating(0)    testDump
                (21)                     |
                                +--------+----------+
                                |        |          |
                             guides   board    playerPiece
                              (24)     (20)      (13)
```

The numbers in parens are the z-position of the nodes.  When I ask the scene for for "nodesAtPoint" and give it a calculated point corresponding to the location of the playerPiece I get: "world, boardLayer, rotating, highlight, board, playerPiece".  This is what I expect.  However when I query the scene for the "nodeAtPoint" using the same point I get back "highlight".  I expected playerPiece.  Why didn't that node get returned?  What am I overlooking?

I'm not sure what good the code will do but here it is.  This code is in Board.m (bottom of the tree).

```
    CGPoint pt = [CheckerUtilities locationFromColumn:column row:row];
    CGPoint p = [self.parent.parent convertPoint:pt toNode:[Globals sharedGlobals].scene];
    NSArray *nodes = [[Globals sharedGlobals].scene nodesAtPoint:p];
    for (SKNode *node in nodes)
      NSLog(@"%@, %@, %f", [node class], node.name, node.zPosition);
    SKNode *checker = [[Globals sharedGlobals].scene nodeAtPoint:p];
    NSLog(@"node: %@", [checker class]);
```

The output is:

```
SKNode, world, 0.000000
BoardLayer, boardLayer, 0.000000
SKSpriteNode, rotating, 0.000000
Highlight, highlight, 21.000000
Board, board, 20.000000
CheckerSprite, checker, 13.000000
node: Highlight
```

Comment: Post your relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> In a scene, when Sprite Kit processes touch or mouse events, it walks
>   the scene to find the closest node that wants to accept the event. If
>   that node doesn’t want the event, Sprite Kit checks the next closest
>   node, and so on. **The order in which hit-testing is processed is
>   essentially the reverse of drawing order.**

In other words, hit testing starts from the last child added to a node to the first (as you stated). However, zPosition not only overrides the draw order but also the hit-test order:

> Sprite Kit uses the zPosition value only to determine the hit testing
>   and drawing order.

The node with the highest z value will be selected first if multiple nodes overlap at the tap point.

Comment: I thought that hit-testing only referred to physics-type contacts and collisions. This is also not a case where anyone tapped anything - it is a programmatically calculated point (see first line of code snippet). Additionally, based upon the z value playing a roll, don't z's only have relative meaning amongst their peers (nodes at same level of the tree)?  Based on your z facts, wouldn't the "nodeAtPoint" come back with "board" then - assuming my peer assumption is right)?

Comment: OK - I just ran a small test by removing the "highlight" sprite.  The answer did indeed com back as "board" supporting the z statement.  However, Apple's description of the 'nodeAtPoint' function: "A descendant in the subtree that intersects the point, or the receiver if no nodes intersect the point. If multiple descendants intersect the point, then the deepest node in the tree is returned. If multiple nodes are at the same level, the intersecting node with the smallest z position is returned."

Comment: Hit-testing has nothing to do with collisions and contacts. It's the process of searching the view hierarchy to find a view that will accept a user's touch. This also applies to SKNodes.

Comment: I read this as well "If multiple nodes are at the same level, the intersecting node with the smallest z position is returned." It is not correct. Hit testing searches from highest to lowest z (makes more sense, right?). You can create a simple test program to prove this to yourself.